# What is the best practice writing massive amount of files to s3 using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs

I'm trying to write about 30k-60k parquet files to s3 using Spark and it's taking a massive amount of time (40+ minutes) due to the s3 rate limit.
I wonder if there is a best practice to do such a thing. I heard that writing the data to HDFS and then copying it using s3-dist-cp may be faster. I can't understand why. isn't the copy from HDFS will take the same amount of time because of the s3 rate limit?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in this approach and works absolutely fine in most of the use cases, but there might be some challenges due to the way in S3 files are written.

**Two Important Concepts to Understand**

1. **S3(Object Store) != POSIX File System : Rename Operation:**

   File rename process in POSIX based file system is a metadata only operation.Only the pointer changes and file remains as is on the disk. For example, I have a file abc.txt and I want to rename it as xyz.txt its instantaneous and atomic. xyz.txt’s last modified timestamp remain same as abc.txt’s last modfied timestamp.
   Where as in AWS S3 (object store) the file rename under the hood is a copy followed by a delete operation. The source file is first copied to destination and then the source file is deleted.So “aws s3 mv” changes the last modified timestamp of destination file unlike POSIX file system.The metadata here is a key value store where key is the file path and value is the content of the file and there is no such process as changing the key and get this done immediately. The rename process depends on the size of the file. If there is a directory rename(there is nothing called directory in S3 for for simplicity we can assume a recusrive set of files as a directory) then it depends on the # of files inside the dir along with size of each file. So in a nutshell rename is very expensive operation in S3 as compared to normal file system.
2. **S3 Consistency Model**

   S3 comes with 2 kinds of consistency a.read after write b.eventual consistency and which some cases results in file not found expectation.Files being added and not listed or files being deleted or not removed from list.

**`Deep explanation:`**

Spark leverages Hadoop’s “FileOutputCommitter” implementations to write data. Writing data again involves multiple steps and on a high level staging output files and then committing them i.e. writing final files.Here the rename step is involved as I was talking earlier from staging to final step.As you know a spark job is divided into multiple stages and set of tasks and due to nature of distributed computing the tasks are prone to failure so there is also provision to re-launch same task due to system failure or speculative execution of slow running tasks and that leads to concepts of task commit and job commit functions.Here we have 2 options of readily available algorithms and how job and task commits are done and having said this not one algorithm is better then other rather based on where we are committing data.

**`mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=1`**

- commitTask renames the data generated by task from task temporary directory to job temporary directory.
- When all the tasks are complete commitJob rename all the data from job temporary directory to final destination and at the end creates _SUCCESS file.

Here driver does the work of commitJob at the end so object stores like S3 may take longer time because of lots of task temporary file being queued up for rename operation(its not serial though)and the write performance is not optimized.It might work pretty well for HDFS as rename is not expensive and just a metadata change.For AWS S3 during commitJob each rename operation of files opens up huge number of API calls to AWS S3 and might cause issues of unexpected API call closure if the number of files are high. It might not also. I have seen both the cases on the same job running in two different times.

**`mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2`**

- commitTask moves data generated by task from task temporary directory directly to the final destination as soon as task is complete.
- commitJob basically writes the _SUCCESS file and doesn't do much.

From a high level this looks optimized but it comes with a limitation not to have the speculative task execution and also if any task fails due to corrupt data then we might end up with residual data in the final destination and needs a clean up. So this algorithm doesn't give 100% data correctness or doesn't work for use cases where we need data in append mode to existing files.Even if this ensures optimised results comes with a risk.The reason for good performance is basically because of less number of rename operations as compared to algorithm 1(still there are renames). Here we might encounter issues of file not found expectations because commitTask writes the file in temporary path and immediately renames them and there are light chances of eventual consistency issues.

***Best Practices***

Here are few I think we can use while writing spark data processing applications :

- If you have a HDFS cluster available then write data from Spark to HDFS and copy it to S3 to persist. s3-dist-cp can be used for data copy from HDFS to S3 optimally.Here we can avoid all that rename operation.With AWS EMR being running for only duration of compute and then terminated afterwards to persist result this approach looks preferable.
- Try avoiding writing files and reading it again and again unless there are consumers for the files , and spark is well known for in-memory processing and careful data persistence/cache in-memory will help the optimized run time of the application.

Comment: Thanks Vijay, about the HDFS, using s3-dist-cp will not cause rename operation? how does the data copied safely? what happened if the copy is aborted in the middle of the process?
and is it better than the Directory Committer that uses HDFS as well?