# Writing to Google Cloud Storage with v2 algorithm safe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-storage

[Recommended settings for writing to object stores](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/cloud-integration.html#recommended-settings-for-writing-to-object-stores) says:

> For object stores whose consistency model means that rename-based commits are safe use the `FileOutputCommitter` v2 algorithm for performance; v1 for safety.

Is it safe to use the v2 algorithm to write out to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage)?

What, exactly, does it mean for the algorithm to be "not safe"? What are the concrete set of criteria to use to decide if I am in a situation where v2 is *not* safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

aah. I wrote that bit of the docs. And one of the papers you cite.

1. GCP implements rename() non-atomically, so v1 isn't really any more robust than v2. And v2 can be a lot faster.
2. Azure "abfs" connector has O(1) Atomic renames, all good.
3. S3 has suffered from both performance and safety. As it is now consistent, there's less risk, but its still horribly slow on production datasets. Use a higher-perfomance committer (EMR spark commtter, S3A committer)
4. Or look at cloud-first formats like: Iceberg, Hudi, Delta Lake. This is where the focus is these days.

### Update October 2022

Apache Hadoop 3.3.5 added in [MAPREDUCE-7341](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-7341) the *Intermediate Manifest Committer* for correctness, performance and scalability on abfs and gcs. (it also works on hdfs, FWIW). it commits tasks by listing the output directory trees of task attempts and saves the list of files to rename to a manifest file, which is committed atomically. Job commit is a simple series of

1. list manifest files to commit, load these as the list results are paged in.
2. create the output dir tree
3. rename all source files to the destination via a thread pool
4. task attempt cleanup, which again can be done in a thread pool for gcs performance
5. save the summary to the _SUCCESS json file, and, if you want, another dir. the summary includes statistics on all store IO done during task and job commit.

This is correct for GCS as it relies on a single file rename as the sole atomic operation.
For ABFS it adds support for rate limiting of IOPS and resilience to the way abfs fails when you try a few thousand renames in the same second. One of those examples of a problem which only surfaces in production, not in benchmarking.

This committer ships with Hadoop 3.3.5 and will not be backported -use hadoop binaries of this or a later version if you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Steve! So succinct yet comprehensive! I'm glad to see 4 (cloud-first formats) mentioned. Is the order important (and Delta should be considered last)?

Comment: hey, no preference, I've no real experience of any of them

Comment: @stevel, Does your recommendation change with spark 3.3? 
Now we have "FileOutputCommitter v2" vs. "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name directory", which is good for S3 ?

Comment: FOC v2 is utterly broken everywhere. hadoop 3.3.5 adds the intermediate manifest committer which doesn't do renames in task commit or dir listings in job commit -just lots of parallel renames. scales better on abfs, correct there and gcs.

Comment: @stevel, thanks for your response. I checked ticket "MAPREDUCE-7341". 
1) It says that FOC v2 has problem with Azure and GCS, do the same problems apply to S3 as well? e.g. the ticket mentions: "The v2 algorithm isn't safe in the presence of failed task attempt commits". Now S3 is consistent, does this apply? 
2) How about atomic directory rename in S3?
3) We have "directory, file, partitioned, magic" for fs.s3a.committer.name, what are the differences there? 
If you could refer to some references on the topic, that'll be great!
Thanks!

Comment: @stevel, I found the answer to Q3 (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html), 

But, in the document, it says: "Now that Amazon S3 is consistent, the magic committer is enabled by default.", so if we don't specify "fs.s3a.committer.name", we use 'magic' by default? but in the table describing the committers, it says for 'file': "the original and unsafe File committer; (default)". Which is the default? and how to tell what committer is actually being used?

Comment: look at the source, provide a patch for the docs....

Comment: oh, and cloudstore jar's committerinfo does tell you what committer the hadoop settings create; doesn't cover the spark binding though. https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore#command-committerinfo

Answer (score 2):

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/transactional-writes-cloud-storage.html

> We see empirically that while v2 is faster, it also leaves behind
> partial results on job failures, breaking transactionality
> requirements. In practice, this means that with chained ETL jobs, a
> job failure — even if retried successfully — could duplicate some of
> the input data for downstream jobs. This requires careful management
> when using chained ETL jobs.

It's safe as long as you manage partial writes on failure. And to elaborate, they mean safe in regard to rename safety in the part you quote. Of Azure, AWS and GCP only AWS S3 is eventual consistent and unsafe to use with the V2 algorithm even when no job failures happen. But GCP (nor Azure or AWS) is not safe in regards to partial writes.

Comment: AWS S3 has been fullly consistent since november. This is really good, but because renames are non-atomic you still have risk of partial failures doing rename. Which, given how long renames take, is much greater than for other stores.

Answer (score 2):

#### FileOutputCommitter V1 vs V2

**1. mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=1**

AM will do mergePaths() in the end after all reducers complete.
If this MR job has many reducers,  AM will firstly wait for all reducers to finish and then use a single thread to merge the outout files.
So this algorithm has some performance concern for large jobs.

**2. mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2**

Each Reducer will do mergePaths() to move their output files into the final output directory concurrently.
So this algorithm saves a lot of time for AM when job is commiting.

- http://www.openkb.info/2019/04/what-is-difference-between.html

If you can see Apache Spark documentation Google cloud marked safe in v1 version so its same in v2

[image]

**What, exactly, does it mean for the algorithm to be "not safe"?**

S3 there is no concept of renaming, so once the data is written to s3 temp location it again copied that data to new s3 location but Azure and google cloud stores do have directory renames

AWS S3 has eventual consistent meaning If you delete a bucket and immediately list all buckets, the deleted bucket might still appear in the list ,eventual consistency causes file not found expectation during partial writes and its not safe.

**What are the concrete set of criteria to use to decide if I am in a situation where v2 is not safe?**

- [What is the best practice writing massive amount of files to s3 using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064820/what-is-the-best-practice-writing-massive-amount-of-files-to-s3-using-spark)

---

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html#ConsistencyModel
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/cloud-integration.html#recommended-settings-for-writing-to-object-stores
- https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/transactional-writes-cloud-storage.html
- https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/files/1604894/a_zero_rename_committer.pdf

Comment: AWS S3 is now consistent. This is a good thing