# Duplicate records as result of Spark Task/Executor Failure

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I have a scenario regarding Spark job and want to understand the behavior.
Scenario:
I am reading data using JDBC connector and writing it to HDFS.

As per my understanding there wont be any data duplication or loss in HDFS even though if a executor/ task fails same sql query will execute on RDBMS. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Eventual consistent target like S3, how it will behave. Is there any concern to use it as target.

Strongly consistent target like GCS bucket, how it will behave.

Thanks in advance

Comment: overwrite, append?

Comment: @thebluephantom, overwrite

Answer (score 0):

s3 is fully consistent now, but awfully slow on rename and rename doesn't reliably fail if the destination exists. You need to use a custom s3 committer (s3a committers, emr optimized committer) for spark/mapreduce. Consult the hadoop and EMR docs for details.

google gcs is consistent, but it doesn't do atomic renames, so the v1 commit protocol, which relies on atomic dir rename, isn't safe. v2 isn't safe anywhere.

The next version of apache hadoop adds a new "intermediate manifest committer" for gcs and abfs performance and correctness.

finally, iceberg is fast and safe everywhere.

Comment: My requirement is to read data from RDBMS process it on Google DataProc cluster using Spark and write it to GCS. If I use overwrite mode with v2 FileOutputCommiter, what are the challenges I may face

Comment: I was referring your answer on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933229/writing-to-google-cloud-storage-with-v2-algorithm-safe". The main concern you have mentioned atomic rename but "https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/cloud-integration.html#recommended-settings-for-writing-to-object-stores" doc is stating GCP file rename is safe for 
gs" connector

Comment: well, that's an old release isn't it? so it's documentation has to be considered out of date. the 3.3.1 docs say otherwise https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/cloud-integration.html#configuring

Comment: v1/v2 algorithms are covered in "a zero rename committer"; review that and decide whether v2 commit meets your needs https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases/tag/tag_release_2021-05-17