# Is it feasible to use deltalake without databricks?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, delta-lake

1. We have our datalake in AWS s3.
2. Metadata in hive, we have a small running cluster.(we havent used Athena/Glue) .
3. We use spark and presto to in our Airflow pipeline.
4. The processed data gets dumped into snowflake.
5. The Detalake has various formats but majorly in parquet.

We want to experiment with Databricks. Our plan is to

1. Create Deltalake tables instead of hive ones for the entire detalake.
2. Use Databricks for processing and warehousing for a significant part of the data.
3. We can not replace snowflake with databricks, at least at this moment.
4. So we need the deltalake tables to be used by other spark pipelines as well.

This last step above, is it possible this way without challenges or is it tricky ?

Comment: Not sure what your exact use case is. But It is possible to use delta format without databricks. It is a open source format. spark
  .xxx
  .xxx
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("delta")
  .save("xxxx")

Answer (score 1):

It was [announced](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/06/30/open-sourcing-all-of-delta-lake.html) that Delta Lake was open sourcing all features in June 2022. So from a feature perspective for Delta Lake itself, this should be more than feasible. I've used Delta Lake in production outside of Databricks to good effect, it's an open-source storage layer that's widely supported.

The concern I see from your list of requirements is concurrent writes to S3 from multiple Spark pipelines. In Databricks there's a managed S3 commit service that handles locking tables during write operations. This is necessary because S3 doesn't support a "put if absent" functionality like some other cloud storage services. Outside of Databricks you'll have to set up your own service using DynamoDB, described [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#multi-cluster-setup).

Comment: In Databricks there's a managed S3 commit service that handles locking tables during write operations.  Can you elaborate? This is for the same table I assume? Or not?

Answer (score 0):

As the 1st answer states, it is feasible. We use HDP on-premise with Hive Delta Connector. We use now all the services that are now available for all, even if not on Databricks platform.

We will be moving to gcp with delta format (and moving to BigQuery). No issues there.

See [Writing to Google Cloud Storage with v2 algorithm safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933229/writing-to-google-cloud-storage-with-v2-algorithm-safe) for a further discussion as mentioned in 2nd part of 1st answer.